# (Almost) adjacency postgres table that has mixed up relations

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I have an (almost) adjacency list postgres table that uses relationships like so:

```
 Id.A   Id.B
   1    4
   2    3
   1    5
   5    6
   7    8
   3    4
   5    7
```

Giving:

```
    1
   / \
  5   4
 / \   \
6   7   3
     \   \
      8   2
```

And I wish to find the node with the smallest value. It isn't necessarily the root, because that doesn't really exist. I need to somehow traverse the graph from any point and find the node with the smallest value. The problem is as things currently are, its not an adjacency table per say.

I am fairly sure this has to use a recursive CTE but dont quite know where to start.

And, as I think I may not have been too clear here, there are a bunch of these graphs all muddled up within the same table, not just one single graph, so for each row it would need to traverse its own graph to find its own smallest value node.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How can be decided if the relationship is correct or not? if the first number is less then the second one? In this case create a new table with the correct order, and then apply a regular CTE expression for computing the root.

Comment: `it is not always the case that id.a is the parent of id.b or visa versa` :: You mean: it is an undirected graph ? (note: in that case there wouldn't be a *root* ) And in the case where it is a DAG, `2` would also be a root.

Comment: If you have a directed graph, you can use `connect_by` option in pg, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html#connectby. see the 2nd example in the `connect_by` section. I think its better to clean the data

Comment: Sorry, failed to show the final node graph that kind of explains my problem a little better. Hopefully it shines more light on my issue.

Comment: What do you mean with `mixed up` ? You swapped A <--> B ? In that case, *any* node can be the root.

Comment: Just been informed I have been asking the wrong question and being very confusing. My apologies, I am still fairly new to all this and I can barely ask the right thing. Sorry for wasting peoples time.

Comment: `there are a bunch of these graphs all muddled up within the same table, not just one single graph` in that case, there would be more than one tree with more than one root: a **forest** in a single table.

Answer (score 0):

The root nodes are the only nodes not showing up in `id.b`, so let's start from there recursively:

```
WITH RECURSIVE roots(root, child) AS (
      SELECT a, a FROM id
      EXCEPT
      SELECT b, b FROM id
   UNION ALL
      SELECT r.root, id.b
      FROM roots r
         JOIN id ON r.child = id.a
) SELECT root, child FROM roots;
```

Comment: Apologies, my question was not clear enough. I have multiple trees mixed up within the same table, and I need to find each nodes own root.
Thank you for your time anyways :)

Comment: But do I understand correctly that my query would return all the roots of all the trees?

Comment: It would yes. Its just I wouldn't know which nodes have which roots.